# Nested Django view with .html inserted using include tag

Tags: python, django, view, nested

I would like to know if anyone has any best practice recommendations for rendering a view within a view in Django, or something with a similar effect where both views can have their own context and methods.

I am currently rendering the dropdown using the built-in include tag. So the nested .html is using the same Django view as the rest of the page. And all the context is coming from the main view as shown below. I would like to give this dropdown its own Django view so that I only perform certain database queries and other calculations if the dropdown is opened.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 d-flex justify-content-center">
        {% include nested.html %}
    </div> ...
```

It would be nice if someone with experience in this could let me know what they think, and if it even makes sense to try and split this into 2 views.

In summary. I would like to know if I can somehow render a separate view using something similar to the include Django tag. So that I have control over where the view gets rendered.

Comment: Can you please provide some code, as i didn't understand what you want :)

Comment: I wont post the actual code as it is long and the question is more speculative. Instead I'll some example code and try and point out in more detail what I would like to do.

Comment: You need a custom inclusion tag.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks, that is what I was looking for. If you submit as answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

Below I have outlined my implementation of the solution below, using custom inclusion tags as suggested in the comments to my question.

You can make a custom template tag file in project directory and then register these in the template library. e.g:

```
template_tags.py

from django import template
from users.models import Organisation
register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('nested.html', takes_context=True)
def nested_template(context, param=None): #param to pass variables from main view 
    context.update({
        'data_list': get_data_list(param)
        'organisation_id': param,
    })
    return context
    def get_data_list(self,param):
        data_list = ... #do all queries needed.
        return data_list
```

In the template tag you point to your nested.html which does whatever you need it to do. For example:

```
nested.html

{% for data in data_list %}
    <h4> {{data}} </h4>
{% endfor %}
```

Then to include the template, in your main view template:

```
{% load nested_template %} #at the top or anywhere before using it

{% nested_template param %} #where you want the template included
```

Hopefully clear enough and may assist someone